# How to justify the vacuum energy density without creation/annihilation operators?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, vacuum, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, classical-field-theory

In *classical field* theory, a well known calculation (pretty involved) gives the following expression for the total energy of the free electromagnetic field in empty space (I'm not writing the MKSA constant $\varepsilon_0$ in front of the integral):
$$\tag{1}
E_{tot} = \frac{1}{2} \int \omega_k^2 \bigl( a_{+}^{*}(k) \, a_{+}(k) + a_{+}(k) \, a_{+}^{*}(k) + a_{-}^{*}(k) \, a_{-}(k) + a_{-}(k) \, a_{-}^{*}(k) \bigr) \, d^3 k,
$$
where $a_{+}(k), \, a_{-}(k) \sim \mathrm{L}^2$ are the *classical* field amplitudes for the right and left polarization states $\varepsilon_{\pm}(k)$.  This expression comes from the standard *classical* Fourier decomposition of the vector-potential $A(x) \sim \mathrm{L}^{-1}$ (a *real* 3-vector):
$$\tag{2}
A(x) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_p\int \Bigl( \varepsilon_p(k) \, a_p(k) e^{i k \,\cdot \, x \,-\, i \omega_k \, t} + \varepsilon_p^{*}(k) \, a_p^{*}(k) e^{-i k \,\cdot \, x \,+\, i \omega_k \, t} \Bigr) \, \frac{d^3 k}{(2 \pi)^{3/2}},
$$
substituted into the field energy:
$$\tag{3}
E_{tot} = \int T_{00} \, d^3 x \sim \mathrm{L}^{-1}.
$$
Energy (1) is similar to the mechanical energy of some classical harmonic oscillator: $E_{osc} \propto \omega^2 a^2$.  The amplitudes have dimensions $\mathrm{L}^2$, since $d^3 k \sim \mathrm{L}^{-3}$ and $\omega(k) \sim \mathrm{L}^{-1}$ (I'm using units such that $c \equiv 1$ and $\hbar \equiv 1$). Now, in *Quantum Mechanics*, the amplitudes are changed to dimensionless operators, with a scale change ($V$ is the volume of some arbitrary part of space):
$$\tag{4}
a_p(k) \quad \Rightarrow \qquad \sqrt{\frac{V}{2 \omega_k(2 \pi)^3}} \: \hat{a}_k,
$$
such that (3) is changed into a field *hamiltonian operator* (and using the commutator $[\hat{a}_k, \hat{a}_k^{\dagger}] = 1$):
$$\tag{5}
\hat{H} = \int \omega_k \bigl( \hat{a}_k^{\dagger} \hat{a}_k + \frac{1}{2} \bigr) \, \frac{d^3 k}{(2 \pi)^3} \, V.
$$
The *classical* vacuum state is defined by the classical amplitudes $a_{\pm}^{\text{vac}}(k) = 0$, so (1) reduces trivially to 0.  In Quantum Mechanics, the vacuum state $|0\rangle$ is such that the vacuum *energy density* isn't 0 (however, see my last comment):
$$\tag{6}
\rho_{\text{vac}} = \frac{\langle0| \hat{H} |0\rangle}{V} = \frac{1}{2} \int \omega_k \, \frac{d^3 k}{(2 \pi)^3}.
$$
This is a well known result.  Well, I never liked the substitution and arbitrary scale transformation (4), just to get the usual *non-relativistic* quantum harmonic oscillator hamiltonian (i.e $\hat{H} = \omega \, (\hat{a}^{\dagger} \hat{a} + \tfrac{1}{2})$), especially since the order of the classical amplitudes is arbitrary: $a_{\pm}^{*}(k) \, a_{\pm}(k) \equiv a_{\pm}(k) \, a_{\pm}^{*}(k)$.  So my question is this:  Is it possible to find back the *vacuum energy density* directly without any annihilation/creation operators $\hat{a}_k, \hat{a}_k^{\dagger}$, **and without introducing an arbitrary $V$ volume factor**?  I'm looking for something like this:
$$\tag{7}
\rho_{\text{vac}} \equiv \langle0| \hat{T}_{00} |0\rangle = \: ?
$$
where $\hat{T}_{00}$ is the time component of the electromagnetic field stress-energy operator.  Is it possible to calculate (7) without using a Fourier expansion like (2) and without using the operators (4)?  I'm especially interested in getting rid of the arbitrary volume $V$ in the scale transformation (4), which I find very doubtful.  Why an undefined or arbitrary volume should enter the calculations to get the quantum vacuum energy density?

I understand that the *classical* (and *quantum*) energy is always defined up to an arbitrary level, so the question may have no answers.  But I'm asking anyway, since there may be something about this that I'm unaware of.

Comment: From my viewpoint, I think that the whole business of reasoning from position representation is just moot. After studying the problems of position in SR+QFT, it is kinda hinting to us that position itself is a non-relativistic thing. Instead, if you think hard about what we may actually be sure of, it is that the free particle Hamiltonian satisfies Einstein energy-momentum relations and thus the momentum eigenstate limit (because they are not normalisable and thus not in Hilbert space, so limiting process needed) is better defined. So we should just start with $H=\omega a^\dagger a$

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent, so you say that we should simply trash that non-zero vacuum energy density (which diverges anyway) all from the start?

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent, if we start with the decomposition (2) as a field *operator* (which is still a solution to the quantum field equation), then the hamiltonian (3) gives (5) again.  But we still have to introduce that arbitrary volume $V$.  This is odd to me.

Comment: Yes, simply trashing out the vacuum energy is baby renormalisation that almost all books end up doing, across both statistical thermodynamics and QFT, and is only really kept in the case of molecules' vibration. The arbitrary volume V is actually nothing to do with QFT. It is that you have chosen to normalise the states using the method of box normalisation. There are other alternatives, for example the one with a division by energy, and Dirac delta distribution.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent, well, this is what I don't understand, about that volume $V$ in (4).  There isn't any box boundaries.  The decomposition (2) is on all space (or an arbitrary volume).  Getting a volume in (4) is simply an arbitrary parameter to define the energy density, and that parameter disappears at the end.  It could be $V \propto \lambda^3$, where $\lambda \propto \omega_k^{-1}$ is the wavelength.

Comment: I don't think one can describe persistent radiation such as radiation in a perfectly reflecting cavity by a Fourier integral of regular functions, one has to use singular functions (delta-like spectral functions) or more naturally, Fourier series. The latter introduces the volume $V$.

Comment: @JánLalinský, can you elaborate on this?  The Fourier integral is more general than series.  The amplitude fonctions could be Dirac deltas... And if we consider a series, we wouldn't get the $d^3 k \,/ (2 \pi)^3$ integral in (6).  My goal is to find (6) directly from (7), if possible without any volume introduced into the calculations.

Comment: Sorry, I meant one can write down Fourier series for equilibrium radiation in arbitrary volume $V$, then the spectral function is nice/defined/finite, because it is an integral of a regular function over finite volume. Trying do describe the same radiation using the Fourier transform leads to difficulties, because what is $\int E(\mathbf x) e^{-i\mathbf k \cdot \mathbf x}d^3\mathbf x$ when $E$ is a homogeneous noise that does not decay in infinity?

Comment: In special case such as $E(\mathbf x)=e^{i\mathbf k_0\cdot\mathbf x}$ the spectral function is a delta distribution, but can we say with certainty this integral defines the spectral function for general $E$?

Comment: I don't think you get (6) from just (7), because (6) depends on the chosen Hamiltonian, but (7) is just a definition in terms of quantum states and energy-momentum tensor, and there is no unique rule that generates $T$ from $H$ or vice versa. At some point we have to decide what is the Hamiltonian we study, and also independently, what is the definition of $T$. In particular, whether we want $H$ with a zero point term, and independently, whether it is part of $T$, or not. This is a matter of definition of what we mean by energy. Already in classical mechanics, $H$ is not always energy $T+U$.

Comment: @JánLalinský, in relativity theory, the energy and the hamiltonian operator are always defined from the energy-momentum tensor (equation (3)).  So I don't understand your last comment.  Once we have $T_{ab}$, then we know $E$.

Comment: EM energy density is always $T_{00}$, but do we have physical grounds for choosing unique $T$ for EM field? We do not, there is infinity of them, differing by some symmetric tensor $\lambda$ with zero divergence. Hamiltonian has even greater degree of freedom, already in classical mechanics, and this does not get better in relativity or quantum theory. Hamiltonian $\int T_{00} d^3 \mathbf x$ and Hamiltonian $\int T_{00} +  \lambda_{00} d^3 \mathbf x$ give the same equations of motion. Hamiltonian with zero point term predicts the same physics as the normally ordered one without that term.

Comment: In other words, (6) is not some uniquely valid result, but a consequence of those chosen Hamiltonian, either (5) or similar variant with the zero point term. But this choice is additional assumption, not implied by (7). Using normally ordered Hamiltonian without the zero point term, we get $\rho_{vac}=0$.

Comment: No, even though the V randomly appeared in Equation (4), actually, if you trace where it came from, it is coming from box normalisation. The version of the normalisation I am using does not have any appearances of V, i.e. it would not appear in the version of Equation (4) that I am using (but I do have Dirac delta distribution appearing, which is equivalent to the $V\to\infty$ limit).